# How do I create a window in react?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any component similar to `ext.window` in react?

I checked `bootstrap/material ui` and the closest thing to a window are modals, but I would like to find something resizable and draggable.

Comment: ext.window is a *draggable modal*, as it is rendered in body tag. It's considered external because is rendered in the root of the DOM.

Comment: I edited my post.This is exactly the functionality I want to achieve that modals don't provide.

Comment: you should be able to accomplish this with `react-draggable`: https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a *draggable modal* with *React* implementation:

**Bootstrap draggable modal**

https://gist.github.com/burgalon/870a68de68c5ed15c416fab63589d503

**Material UI draggable modal**

https://codesandbox.io/s/nnq98zlrrl

Answer (score 3):

You can try specific components that do this, like [react-rnd](https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd).

See the demo, you can both resize and drag the created component.

Here, you have a live example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xpm699v4lp).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Material-Ui for a while.
There's a standard modal and dialog (like a modal but with default template for easier customization)

Isn't modal (dialog) sufficient for the job that you want?

Comment: I would like to use something that you can resize and drag around, but if I don't find anything like that,I'll stick to modals.